# Modules correctly working in Jupyter Lab but NOT in VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, pygame

I recently wanted to try coding with Pandas and Pygame on my Laptops VSCode, but got to some hard to solve problems that I managed to fix and now have come to a problem that I cant seem to solve.

On Jupyter Lab my Pandas and Pygame works perfectly, no problems or nothing and the basics work quite well. Importing Pandas or Pygame on Jupyter Lab gives me no errors even when I do actual code with it.

Now on VSCode on the other hand if I try to import them it gives me this error:

Pygame:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Joona/Pictures/pygametest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame as pyg
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

Pandas:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    import pandas as pd
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\joonan\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

Other threads that I found say that reinstalling Pandas and Pygame works, but it did not work for me.
For

Comment: It is not clear in your post what do you use in your python environment. Are the packages installed globally or do you use a venv ? Are you in the right working directory? I would recommend you search how to make a virtual environment in python and use it in your VS Code project. There is plenty of literature of that online.

Comment: VScode may be using different version of Python or different python library, try this to in both Jupyter Notebook and VSCode `from sysconfig import get_paths as gp; print(gp()['include'])`

Comment: anxiousPI may be right, check if you are using a venv. You may be able to just create a new venv and install the required modules that you need with pip

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the same environment in the Jupyter notebook and python file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Zack Evergreen Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )